# How to view code deployed on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I have deployed my REST based java application on Heroku.
Everything is working fine. However I can see code on heroku dashboard as other developers working with me also want to collaborate.
Do they need to clone .git repository given in settings page of application.
Please help how to do this ?
And how to push code to bitbucket so my code doesn't get vanished?

Answer (score 9):

When you create application on Heroku it automatically gets Git repo - it's a normal repo so you colleagues can just clone it (if they're added as contributors) as you said.

To push code to bitbucket, create repo there and add it as a remote to your local git configuration. Then just push to heroku remote and bitbucket remote at will. For automated solution you can consider Github Integration: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration

Comment: just did that but apparently it is not the case